# How to Use regular expression in Redash Mongo Json Query

Tags: redash

I have MongoDB as Data source. I want to query in redash which will be the equivalent following:-

```
db.collection.find({“templateId”:/XYZ$/})
```

This query return all data from the collection where key `templateId` end with string XYZ. How can I use the same in redash JSON?

Also please help in using $exist in Redash.

Answer (score 2):

I use this example with Redash.

```
{
    "collection": "Users",
    "query": {
        "Phone": {
            "$regex": "1234$",
            "$options": "i"
        }
    }
}
```

Options i to make it case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Got here from googling the same question.

It seems to me that next pipeline step works:

```
{"$match": {"templateId": {"$regex": "XYZ$"}}}
```